# how to add the vertx/JDBCClient classes to dockerfile

Tags: docker, vert.x

I have added the vertx/vertx3 to docker file and in my server I have user JDBCClient connection for database connection. I'm getting the following error.

```
Could not load driverClass org.postgresql.Driver
```

In dockerfile I have added

```
FROM vertx/vertx3
```

Can any one explain the exact problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the postgressqlDriver jar file into the container and into vert.x Classpath.

Copy the postgressql Driver into your projectfolder (for example in the folder 
`lib`) and than something like

```
COPY lib/yourPostgresSqlDriver.jar $VERTICLE_HOME
```

in your Dockerfile should do the work, if you build and use your container like in https://hub.docker.com/r/vertx/vertx3/ described.

Comment: dockerfile not taking the Jar file path, its telling that       lstat home/msuser1/Downloads/postgresql-42.1.4.jar: no such file or directory

Comment: docker build only take files in the local directory into account for building the docker image. copy the postgresql-42.1.4.jar into a your project directory, perhaps in the ./lib directory and than use COPY lib/ postgresql-42.1.4.jar $VERTICLE_HOME